# Getting 403 error when jquery dialog box submits

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

So I got the jquery dialog box working to where it calls a script via ajax on open to populate the form field inside the dialog box. Everything is working, however when I click the action button to update the record in the dialog box I get a 403 error in FireBug. After researching its when I have this value in any of my fields that causes the 403 error:

```
http://
```

If I take out http:// in any of the fields in the dialog box then the action button works just fine. Here is my function when they click the action button to update. Do I need to encoding it some how prior to serializing it?

```
"Update Form": function() {

                if($("#UpdateForm").validate().form() == true) {

                    var formSend = $("#UpdateForm"); 
                    var formData = formSend.serialize();

                    $('#formresults').html('<tr><td colspan="4"><span>Loading form results...</span></td></tr>');

                    $.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        cache:false,
                        url:'/update_form.php?action=updateform',
                        data:formData,
                        dataType:'json',
                        success: function(data) {

                            $('#formresults').html(data.records);

                        }

                    });

                }

                return false;

            }
```

Comment: jsfiddle playground would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, this had nothing to do with jquery. Apparently this was tripping a rule in the apache security mod installed on the server. Sorry again.